# Error changed system cannot find file specified

Tags: java, file, runtime-error

```
package q1;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * <p>This is where you put your description about what this class does. You
 * don't have to write an essay but you should describe exactly what it does.
 * Describing it will help you to understand the programming problem better.</p>
 *
 * @author Your Name goes here
* @version 1.0
*/
public class Household {
 /**
 * <p>This is the main method (entry point) that gets called by the JVM.</p>
 *
 * @param args command line arguments.
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // your code will go here!!!
    Survey s1 = new Survey();
    s1.getSurveyList();
    System.out.println();
}

};
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        package q1;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Survey {
        ArrayList<Integer> surveyList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        public Survey(){

        }

        public ArrayList<Integer> getSurveyList() throws FileNotFoundException{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("survey.txt"));

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                sc.useDelimiter(" ");
                int i = sc.nextInt();
                surveyList.add(i);
            }

            System.out.println(surveyList.get(0));
            sc.close();

            return surveyList;
        }


    }
```

Now it says that the system cannot find the file specified. Not sure how to use the File class because it is the first time I have had to do it.
Any ideas? Also how would one format the output of the text file so that it displays it in a table? Is there some method that does that?

Comment: try `new File("survey.txt")`, i.e add the extension.

Comment: tried new File("survey.txt") and also many other formats used online like (src/p1/survey.txt) and also tried putting survey.txt into every folder in my project and using the name only. Nothing seems to get the program to work.

Comment: check that the file exists in the location you're expecting, add this statement to your main method to see what is your working directory `System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath());`. Using `new File("survey.txt")` means that the file has to be the directory the statement will print.

Comment: Commented out my whole code and simply put
    System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath());
and I still got the error Could not find or load main class q1.Survey

Comment: this error is not related to the File class at all, your program haven't been compiled. The JVM trys to load the class `q1.Survey` but does not find it! Please clean your project, resolve any compilation errors and try to run it.

Comment: I just found an issue. I had two main methods in the same package.
Question though. How would I use the code I have here in a class and not in a main method. I need to sort the txt file and put it into an array list.

Comment: move it to another (instance or class) method, main is just a static method too and happens to be the entry point of java programs.

Answer (score 1):

The error "Could not find main class" has nothing to do with the way you are using the File or Scanner class. It sounds like your classpath is wrong. Ensure that your project root is configured correctly. You could try to use [this tutorial for using Eclipse](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_run_configuration.htm) for a reference on how to set up your project correctly. If you are not using an IDE, check out the contents of the file you are running and make sure the correct information is in there. It would help a lot if you could specify your question a lot more such as which operating system are you using, are you using an IDE (if yes, which one), are you compiling it as a jar file or are you running it from a directory with class files... etc.

Comment: The projects are set up by the prof. Our job is to solve the questions we are given and get back to him and I just tested the program, it doesnt seem to be running without any of my code either. Going to try to re-download the file.

Comment: Can you tell me what the content of the file you download looks like? Do you open it with a specific program, or are you just editing the files with a text editor? How are you running it, are you clicking a file to run it (such as a .bat file or a bash/shell script on linux)?

Comment: We download a zip file containing the checkstyle, build and src files. Everything is set up so that when we run ant, we get the file that we submit to the prof. The Src contains 4 packages with 1 to 2 classes each. here is an imgur http://imgur.com/PVnidkm

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your ant build file and the contents of the file you are using the run it?

Comment: if you look at the top, you will see that I managed to get my Main to run but still cant get eclipse to find my survey.txt

Comment: Put the survey.txt next to build.xml file (in the project root directory). Let me know if that works.

Comment: I just solved it actually. Placed it into the src folder. Then changed my method to Doubles instead.
    public ArrayList<Double> getSurveyList() throws                 FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(
                new File("src" + File.separator + "survey.txt"));

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            Double i = sc.nextDouble();
            Household.add(i);
        }
        sc.close();

        return Household;
    }

Comment: Congrats buddy! Good luck in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Changed Array to Double instead of Integer and changed the scanner line to this:
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(
                new File("src" + File.separator + "survey.txt"));